# Setting a maximum limit for items in a cluster

Tags: postgis, clustering

I am combining dbscan and kmeans to get clusters with 1 to 10 items. Here is my code so far:

```
with data as(
select at2."name" as area_type, a.name,bf.* from building_footprints bf
left join area a on bf."areaID" = a."ID"
left join area_type at2 on at2."ID" = a."areaTypeID"
where a."ID" in (select "areaID" from campaign_scope)
and at2."name"='Uc'
)
,
dbscan as(
select data.*,ST_ClusterDBSCAN(st_transform(data."geoJson",24313),eps := 50, minPoints := 1) 
  OVER(ORDER BY data."ID") AS cluster_id from data)
,

filter as(
select cluster_id,count("ID") from dbscan
group by cluster_id
having count("ID") < 10
) 

,

accepted_dbscan as
(
select area_type, name,"ID","geoJson", "cluster_id" from dbscan 
where cluster_id in (select cluster_id from filter)

)
,

rejected_dbscan as 
(
select * from dbscan 
where cluster_id not in (select cluster_id from filter)
)


,
kmeans as(
select "area_type", "name",
  "ID", 
  "geoJson" ,
  ST_ClusterKMeans(rejected_dbscan."geoJson", (select (count(*)/10)::integer from rejected_dbscan) ) OVER (order by rejected_dbscan."ID") AS cluster_id
FROM rejected_dbscan
)
,
finalset as (
select * from kmeans 
union
SELECT * from accepted_dbscan
)

select cluster_id, count(*) as bfp_count from finalset 
group by 1
order by bfp_count desc
```

The problem is that the result set has clusters with more than 10 buildings as well, first few rows shown:

```
cluster_id        bfp_count
702               46
352               40
881               38
305               37
```

How do I limit cluster size to a maximum of 10? Please note, I can not simply discard the bigger clusters, but I want to break them down further.

Comment: am I better off just using ST_ClusterWithin?